# How many contiguous sub-arrays can be formed from an array?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I would like to learn the mathematical solution to finding the number of different contiguous subsets  that can be formed from an array.

For example, I understand the number of subsets (in general) possible from an array A={1...n} is 2^n.

But if only contiguous subsets were allowed from the array, how many different subsets can we form?

For example, A= {9,2,3,4}

Few contiguous subsets are : {9}, {9,2}, {9,2,3}, {2,3}

Answer (score 2):

If 
$$
S = \left\{a_1, \ldots , a_n \right\}
$$
for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$ we define
$$
S_{i,j} = \left\{a_i,a_{i+1},\ldots a_{j - 1}, a_j \right\}
$$
note that $|S_{i,j}| = j - i + 1$. For $1 \leq k \leq n$ we have
$$
S_{i,i+k-1} = \left\{a_i, \ldots, a_{i + k - 1}\right\}
$$
we have the bound $i \leq n - k + 1$, each set $S_{i,j}$ contains contiguous elements so I'd say
$$
N = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} |S_{i,i+k-1}| = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n-k)
$$
should give you the number of contiguous subsets.

Comment: Does this assume that the array has numbers in incremental order? The elements would be random in the array.

Comment: You didn't say that xD.

Comment: Is my interpretation of contiguous correct at least?

Comment: I've corrected the example in the question now. I will work out your interpretation of contiguous subsets in A= {1....n} (increasing order), please give me sometime.

Comment: It shouldn't change my answer. There's a bijection between the set S I've defined and any of it's permutations, so the answer doesn't change.

Comment: Changed my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume we want only non-empty subsets then:
for the set {a1, a2, a3, ..., an}
number of subsets with length 1 is n : {a1} , {a2} , ... , {an}
number of subsets with length 2 is n-1 : {a1,a2} , {a2,a3} , ... , {an-1, an}
...
number of subsets with length n is 1 : {a1, a2, a3, ..., an}

Therefore the sum is n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 = **n(n+1)/2**

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Each nonempty contiguous sublist of $[1,...,n]$ has a least element $a$ and a greatest element $b$.

Thus, you want to count the number of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $1 \le a \le b \le n$.

For the case $a<b$, the count is the same as the number of two-element subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$, so the the count is ____ ?

For the case $a=b$, the count is ____ ?

Finally, if the empty list is regarded as contiguous, boost the count by $1$.

Comment: You say- "Each nonempty contiguous subset of {1,...,n} has a least element 'a' and a greatest element 'b'."

But a subset such as {1} is allowed as well.

Comment: @Komal-SkyNET: That's covered by the case $a=b$.